# input file event onchange no work when button click input file

Tags: javascript

I fire input file via JS function like this:

```
function PujarFitxerGP() {
document.getElementById('FUFitxer').click();
};
```

This control have a onchange event to validate the file:

```
<input type="file" onchange="ValidateGP();return false;" ID="FUFitxer" style="display:none" />
```

Event is firing correctly but when I get the input file by Id not contains the file:

```
document.getElementById('FUFitxer').files[0].name; ------>UNDEFINED
```

If I do the same via input file (changing style="display:none") is working as expected.

How I can resolve this problem? What I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `onchange` event's parameter to access the files object on change

```js
function ValidateGP(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  console.log(file.name);
}

function PujarFitxerGP() {
  document.getElementById('FUFitxer').click();
};
```

```css
#FUFitxer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="FUFitxer" onchange="ValidateGP(event)" />

<button onclick="PujarFitxerGP(event)">Click here!</button>
```

Comment: When I do this is work as expected!!Thanks